# Adding margin to div pushes it off the screen

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I would like to have a 5px margin around each of my divs but when I add it in CSS, there is a 5px margin on every side except for in between the divs and on the bottom. The two divs also overflow off the page on the bottom. I understand this is because of the 5px margin on top pushing the divs off screen. I am unsure how to make it just add the margin all around and shrink the divs accordingly.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
```

> Resulting Page

*Divs pushed off screen on bottom and no margin in-between divs. 5px margin on top, left, and right is present.*

[image: resulting page]

I am new to HTML and CSS so any helps greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not going to give a full answer as there will be a duplicate out there. Read up on the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model). Your total sizetill be 100% + magins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CSS Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; }

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex; /* Use flex! */
  padding: 5px; /* Instead of children margin */
  /* gap: 5px; /* Uncomment to add a gap between your child elements! */
}

.one,
.two {
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.one { width: 10%; background: red;  }
.two { width: 90%; background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`box-sizing: border-box` does *not* include handling/including of margins in the overall width or height of the elements, only padding and borders. Therefore you have to subtract the margin values from the width or height values.

In your case you should use `calc` values on all `height` and `width` settings where there's a margin. I.e. if you have 5px margin (= on all sides), use for example `calc(100% - 10px)` where you want 100% width or height. Similar with other percentage values - see your adapted code below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(10% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(90% - 10px);
  height: calc(10% - 10px);
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the css calc function on the width of `.two` to subtract 10px (2x5px margins) from the 90% width, appears to give a reasonable margin.

```
width: calc(90% - 10px);
```

I am not sure why there is not a visible 10px (2x5px) margin between `.one` and `.two` though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(90% - 10px);
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
```